# Using storm-kafka-0.8-plus , only a few spouts actually pull data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have been using storm-kafka-0.8-plus with kafka 0.8.1.1 & storm 0.9.0.1 (zmq reason.). I have also used the spout with other versions of storm. But the issue is only a few of the threads actually work and others remain idle. I have no clue why this is happening.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    brokerHosts = new ZkHosts(CONFIGURATION.getString("ZK_HOSTS") + "/"
            + CONFIGURATION.getString("ZK_CONNECT_PATH"));
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts,
            CONFIGURATION.getString("KAFKA_TOPIC"),
            CONFIGURATION.getString("ZOOKEEPER_STORAGE_PATH"),
            CONFIGURATION.getString("ZOOKEEPER_STORAGE_ID"));
    spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
    KafkaSpout kafkaspout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("kafka-spout", kafkaspout,
            CONFIGURATION.getInt("NUM_KAFKA_SPOUT_THREADS"));

    Config config = new Config();
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(CONFIGURATION.getString("TOPOLOGY_NAME"),
            config, builder.createTopology());
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.wurstmeister.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-kafka-0.8-plus</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: check (number of spout executors == number of partition) in kafka. also check all configurations for partitions both at storm and kafka level.

Comment: @kartik : thanks for the reply. Yes, spout executors < number of partition. The thing is that if I run the same topology with storm 0.9.3 and storm-kafka 0.9.3, it works fine. However I want to stick to storm 0.9.0.1 for zero mq reason.